# Is it possible to host ejabberd on IIS in windows 2008 or 2012?

Tags: iis, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to build and android app based on [XMPP (ejabberd)](https://www.ejabberd.im/), But my server is an Windows 2012 and I do not have a Linux server. Is there any step-by-step strait forward instructions on how to install and configure ejabberd on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install or run an XMPP server in IIS.
But ejabberd is cross platform and runs also on Windows. So you can download the and install eJabberd on your windows machine from here:
https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install ejabberd or any other XMPP server like Openfire in windows in which IIS is installed.